# SQLITE_ERROR: near "?" when adding a column in ExpressJS

Tags: sqlite, express, syntax, syntax-error, alter-table

this is my first question here. I've been trying to get a column added to a database, using ExpressJS and sqlite3. Normally I use a question mark as a placeholder/parameter, but in this case I get an error. I've been struggling with this for hours but I can't get it to work. This is the error I get:

[Error: SQLITE_ERROR: near "?": syntax error] {
  errno: 1,
  code: 'SQLITE_ERROR'
}

Hope you guys can help me!

```
        var scoreOfGame = req.body.game + "_Score";
```

db.all("ALTER TABLE Users ADD COLUMN ? INT", [scoreOfGame], (error, results) => {

```
    if (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
    else {
        console.log(results)

    }
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using ? as a placeholder, I rewrote it to this:

```
db.all(`ALTER TABLE Users ADD COLUMN ${scoreOfGame} INT`)
```